# php current weekdays name with date

Tags: php, date

I want to create a list of weekday dates with name of the weekday.
If today is monday - 2017-01-02 (Y-m-d), then I want the list to be something like this:

- Mon-02 | Tue-03 | Wed-04 | Thu-05 | Fri-06 | Sat-07 | Sun-08

My code below will give such result, if today is monday.
This is what I have so far.

```
    function NextDayDate($day) {
       return new DateTime('next ' . $day);
    }

    $dt = new DateTime();
    $today=date("l");

    if ($today=="Monday") {
      echo $dt->format('d'); // Todays date
      echo '</br>';
    }
    elseif ($today!="Monday"){
        echo '</br>';
      $nextMonday = NextDayDate('Monday');
    echo $nextMonday->format('d'); // Next date
    echo '</br>';
    }
if ($today=="Tuesday") {
      echo $dt->format('d'); // Todays date
      echo '</br>';
    }
    elseif ($today!="Tuesday"){
        echo '</br>';
      $nextMonday = NextDayDate('Tuesday');
    echo $nextMonday->format('d'); // Next date
    echo '</br>';
    }
```

If today is Tuesday, then for monday I will have Mon-09 because that is the next date for monday.

- Mon-09 | Tue-03 | Wed-04 | Thu-05 | Fri-06 | Sat-07 | Sun-08

I want to keep last days date so the list does not change.

Maybe there is a way to get current weeks day names with date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much more easy:

```
$a = new DateTime();
$oneDay = new DateInterval("P1D");
// Here you add one day to your date until it will Monday
while ($a->format('D') != 'Mon') {
  $a->add($oneDay);  
}
// Here you print 7 days from your target Monday
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
  echo $a->format("D-d");   
  $a->add($oneDay); 
}
```